# How to make a line break in a string or get a string from html with tags pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code like this that implements the typewriter effect. I take the text from the tag into html and then paste it back with the effect.

The only thing is that `<br>` tags is not taken into account, and the text is inserted on one line.

How can I get the text along with tags or manually add it from JS?

```js
    var str = document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').textContent || document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').innerText,
      i = 0,
      isTag,
      text;
  (function type() {
      text = str.slice(0, ++i);
      if (text === str) return;
      document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').style.display = 'inline';
      document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').innerHTML = text;

      var char = text.slice(-1);
      if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
      if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

      if (isTag) return type();
      setTimeout(type, 80);
  }());
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title-main"><h1 style="display: none;">TEXT!<br>TEXT,<br>TEXT </h1></div>
```

Comment: How about change `.textContent` and `.innterText` of `var str` to `.innerHTML`?

Comment: Wow, it's that simple. Thanks you!

Comment: Thank you for trying it :) I'm glad it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about change `.textContent` and `.innterText` of `var str` to `.innerHTML`?

```js
var str = document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').innerHTML,
      i = 0,
      isTag,
      text;
  (function type() {
      text = str.slice(0, ++i);
      if (text === str) return;
      document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').style.display = 'inline';
      document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1').innerHTML = text;

      var char = text.slice(-1);
      if( char === '<' ) isTag = true;
      if( char === '>' ) isTag = false;

      if (isTag) return type();
      setTimeout(type, 80);
  }());
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title-main"><h1 style="display: none;"> TEXT!<br>TEXT,<br>TEXT </h1></div>
```